# Electrical problems with gauges while fuses keep blowing

Tags: electrical, toyota, corolla, fuse, gauges

I've got a problem with my 2000 Corolla ... my cluster gauges( rev counter, temp, Speedo) as well as my windows (electronic) aren't working and the fuses are popping/blowing. My battery seems to be draining as well. And idea what could cause this?. Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Usually when fuses keep blowing, you have an electrical short somewhere. If you track the wiring associated with the fuses which are blowing, you should be able to figure out where the short is at. It has to be somewhere between the fuse and what the fuse powers. If the radio fuse is going out, then track the wiring between the radio fuse and the radio. There may be more than one short, but I'd bet these shorts are all occuring in the same general location.